запуск php на VScodium

Подскажите как запустить php на vscodium?
Я установил xampp и прописал пути в переменных среды в виндовс как показано, но почему-то ошибка все равно висит. Что делать?
прописал пути к php.exe и php.ini в VSCodium.. теперь просто пустая страница открывается, хотя на ошибки не жалуется.
--- вопрос решился. поставили live server запускаю его потом live five тогда работает!
